# How to get html() from element excluding another element?

Tags: jquery

Sorry for real stupid question. But it does not work either way.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='js/jquery.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var htmlcontent = $('.content').not('.dontgrab').html();
    alert(htmlcontent); // returns EVERYTHING
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class='content'>
  BEFORE
  <div class='dontgrab'>DON'T GRAB</div>
  AFTER
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Tried $(".content *:not('.dontgrab')").html(); // returns NULL

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: @DavidRodrigues: nope. already tried.

Comment: Thanks guys. I guess it will be much easy to remove() element and then just re-create it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var clone = $('div.content').clone();
clone.find('.dontgrab').remove();

var html = clone.html();
```

Comment: Will this remove .dontgrab element from the document? I need to keep it!

Comment: You will clone it (temporarily), you will remove only from clone, not from document.

Comment: Any other ways? Seems to be a little extra coding. =)

Comment: The `.html()` function return the HTML code from a selected element, not *render* a HTML code based on all selections. If you have more than one on selector, it will use the first selected element. So, you need use this way, seems the better.

Comment: This is odd! Don't even need jQuery for this.

Comment: The `.html()` is useful for crossbrowser. If you just use `.innerHTML` prop you will get differents results in differents browsers.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7350/discussion-between-david-rodrigues-and-radio)

Answer (score -1):

I think you are trying to do:

```
var htmlcontent = $('.content').remove(".dontgrab").html();
```

You could use .not() if the situation was like:

```
var htmlcontent = $('div').not(".dontgrab").html();

<body>
<div class="content">
  BEFORE  

  AFTER
</div>
<div class="content dontgrab">DON'T GRAB</div>
</body>
```

I dont think you can use .not for selected elements children. I hope it helps